# problemas con registro de base de datos termina nulo o salta de registro

Tags: ruby

bueno tengo el siguiente problema quisiera que cada vez que pase el ciclo guardar cada  variable dentro de la base de datos pero no logro hacerlo me guarda o un registro vacio o un registro con el codigo el tipo de orden y la fecha en otro registro. ya tengo creado un CRUD

esto es mas o menos lo que quiero

```
           if line.start_with?('UNH')               
               clave     = line[0..4]
              guadar variable clave  em mi base de datos y seguir en el mismo regitro hasta leer la ultima variable
           end            

      if line.start_with?('DTM137')
         clave  = line[0..5]
         fechag = line[6...14]
         guardar fecha dentro del mismo registro
      end
```

este es mi codigo

```
           File.foreach('ojo.txt').with_object([]) do |line, result|

            if line.start_with?('UNH')
               clave     = line[0..4]
               result << "#{clave} ORDEN DE COMPRA"    
            end            

          if line.start_with?('BGM')
              clave     = line[0..2]
              codigooc = line[6...26]

               if line.include?('BGM2') 
                  region = 'ORDEN DE COMPRA '
               else                    
                  region = 'ORDEN DE COMPRA SUGERIDA'
               end

               if cajas = '1'  
                  region = 'CANCELACION'
               end

              if cajas = '9'
                 region = 'ORIGINAL'
              end

              if cajas = '6'
                 region = 'PROPUESTA'
              end 

              result << "#{clave} codigo #{region}, #{@codigooc}"

              Encabezado.create!(numero_oc: codigooc, tipo_oc: region)

          end



      if line.start_with?('DTM137')
          #line.delete(' ')
          clave     = line[0..5]
          fechag = line[6...14]
          result << "#{clave} ,FECHA DE GENERACION MENSAJE #{fechag}"

      end




    if line.start_with?('DTM ')
        clave    = line[0..2]
        fechaen = line[5...13]
        result << "#{clave} , FECHA DE ENTREGA: #{fechaen}"
                       #Encabezado.create!(fechaen: fechaen)
    end



    if line.start_with?('DTM157')# 
       fechalist = line[6...14]
       clave = 'DTM157'
       result << "#{clave} , FECHA DE LISTA DE PRECIOS: #{fechalist}"

    end

      if line.start_with?('NADBY')              
        clave     = line[0..4]
        comprador = line[6...-1]            
        result << "#{clave} , codigo comprador #{comprador}"
      end

     if line.start_with?('NADSU')
        clave     = line[0..4]
        comprador = line[6...-1]
        result << "#{clave} , codigo proveedor #{comprador}"
     end

    if line.start_with?('CTAOC')               
       clave     = line[0..4]
       comprador = line[5...-1]
       result << "#{clave} , INFORMACION PROVEEDOR #{comprador}"
    end

    if line.start_with?('PAT')
       clave     = line[0..2]
       tpago = line[5]
       dentrega = line[7..8]
       dpagar = line [-3..-1]
        result << "#{clave} , codigo #{tpago} , condiciones normales #{tpago} , dias para entrega #{dentrega}  , Dias para pagar #{dpagar} "
    end


       if line.start_with?('TODNC')
          clave     = line[0..4]
          flete1 = 'flete por cuenta del vendedor sin costo'
               else
          flete2 = 'flete por cuenta del comprador'
        result << "#{clave} #{flete2}"
       end

        if line.start_with?('LOC')
          clave     = line[0..2]
          lugar = line[5]
          codigolugar = line[6...-1]
          result << "#{clave} direccion de entrega #{codigolugar}"
        end
```

imagen de la base de datos y como guarda los registros vacios o guarda lo que deberia ser un registro en dos... intente poner los demas campos y no me los toma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y cuando llega a `Encabezado.create!(numero_oc: codigooc, tipo_oc: region)`, ¿te has cerciorado de que vaya algo en esos campos que le pasas como parámetro?

Comment: si inclusive puse a ver en pantalla el valor de cada campo y tiene su valor.. alguna otra forma de hacerlo? en ruby si declaro una variable dentro de un if muere su valor cuando salga del if? .. intente con una variable globar a ver y tampoco....

Comment: Me refería si has hecho un `puts codigooc` o  `puts region` una línea antes de crear el encabezado. Y si lo has hecho ¿has verificado a través de `rails c` que los encabezados tienen la información guardada en la bd?

Comment: si amigo ya verifique que tienen un dato solucione con la linea 
 ***Encabezado.create(numero_oc: codigooc , tipo_oc: region , fecha_g: a , fecha_en: fechaen)*** pero ahora no me guarda la fehca y ninguno de los otros campos....